# Runtime of Dynamic Programming Solution from Previous Post (Balls into Bins)

Tags: algorithm, performance, time, dynamic-programming

In the question
[Calculating How Many Balls in Bins Over Several Values Using Dynamic Programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36247061/calculating-how-many-balls-in-bins-over-several-values-using-dynamic-programming/36247319)
the answer discusses a dynamic programming algorithm for placing balls into bins, and I was attempting to determine the running time, as it is not addressed in the answer.

A quick summary: Given M indistinguishable balls and N distinguishable bins, the entry in the dynamic programming table Entry[i][j] represents the number of unique ways i balls can be placed into j bins.

```
S[i][j] = sum(x = 0 -> i, S[i-x][j-1])
```

It is clear that the size of the dynamic programming 2D array is O(MN). However, I am trying to determine the impact the summation has on the running time.

I know a summation of values (1....x) means we must access values from 1 to x. Would this then mean, that for each entry computation, since we must access at most from 1...M other values, the running time is in the realm of O((M^2)N)?
Would appreciate any clarification. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid excessive time for summation if you keep column sums in additional table.

When you calculate `S[i][j]`, also fill `Sums[i,j]=Sums[i-1,j] + S[i,j]` and later use this value for the cell at right side  `S[i,j+1]`

P.S. Note that you really need to store **only two rows or even one row** of sum table